# Gesprochene Sprache lernen

Tags: learning, resource, spoken-language, conversation

Können Sie mir bitte zwei Bücher oder Quellen empfehlen, die die folgenden Eigenschaften haben:

1. Man soll damit die in Alltag gesprochene Sprache lernen können.
2. Man soll damit Sätze oder Fragen (Diskussion) lernen können, die man täglich in verschiedenen Situationen benötigt, z.B. beim Friseur, im Supermarkt, beim Vorstellungsgespräch oder bei anderen alltäglichen Situationen.

Comment: Viele Dank fürs Korrigieren

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich würde eine Sammlung von sogenannten "Dialogkarten" empfehlen, oder eine andere Quelle mit diesem Schwerpunkt. "Dialoge" oder "Gespräche" sind die Situationen in denen sich mehrere Personen miteinander unterhalten.

Ein paar einfache Beispiele wären:

- Wie heißt du? / Wie heißen Sie? (Ich heiße... / Mein Name ist...)
- Was möchten Sie trinken? (Ich hätte gern ein Wasser. / Ein Wasser bitte.)
- Zahlen Sie mit Karte? (Ja/Nein)

Einige kostenlose Karten sind hier zu finden: [www.deutschblog.de](https://deutschlernerblog.de/fragen-und-antworten-dialogkarten-a1-fuer-erste-gespraeche-auf-deutsch/) Es gibt aber bestimmt noch mehr Quellen unter dem Suchbegriff "Dialoge" oder "Gespräche".

*english*

I would recommend some dialogue cards, or other sources with the focus on dialogues. "Dialoge" or "Gespräche" are this situations, where some people talk to each other.

Some free examples are provided in the link above. But there are more sources for sure, you may find with the search terms "Dialoge" or "Gespräche".

Answer (score 2):

Gesprochene Sprache kann man nicht aus Büchern lernen. In Büchern steht zwangsweise immer geschriebene Sprache. Gesprochene Sprache lernt man, indem man mit Menschen spricht. Es hilft auch, sich Filme oder Fernsehserien anzusehen.

Dazu kommt, das es zwar einen halbwegs einheitlichen Standard für geschriebenes Deutsch gibt, aber beim gesprochenen Deutsch gibt es große regionale Unterschiede. Viele Redewendungen, die in Zürich üblich sind, werden von Menschen in Dresden nicht versanden. Mit der in Wien erlernten gesprochenen Sprache kann es einem passieren, dass man in Köln nicht verstanden wird. Und wenn man so spricht, wie es in Bremen üblich ist, kann es mitunter sein, dass man in München nicht verstanden wird.